# TextSecure Signal Server - Certificate Error

Tags: java, linux

I was trying to deploy Signal Server according to the guidelines here.
[Link](https://github.com/aqnouch/Signal-Setup-Guide/tree/master/signal-server)

Everything was success in the build part. But when i run the service using this command

```
java -jar service/target/TextSecureServer-3.21.jar server service/config/config.yml
```

I am getting below errors.

```
INFO  [2020-09-10 04:52:48,319] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering jersey handler with root path prefix: /
INFO  [2020-09-10 04:52:48,320] io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory: Registering admin handler with root path prefix: /
org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMException: problem parsing cert: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in factory: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERUnknownTag
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader$X509CertificateParser.parseObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMReader.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.push.RetryingApnsClient.initializeCertificate(RetryingApnsClient.java:76)
    at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.push.RetryingApnsClient.<init>(RetryingApnsClient.java:49)
    at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.push.APNSender.<init>(APNSender.java:70)
    at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.run(WhisperServerService.java:246)
    at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.run(WhisperServerService.java:151)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:44)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:94)
    at org.whispersystems.textsecuregcm.WhisperServerService.main(WhisperServerService.java:406)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in factory: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERUnknownTag
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:355)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown object in factory: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERUnknownTag
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.TBSCertificateStructure.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.TBSCertificateStructure.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509CertificateStructure.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509CertificateStructure.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKX509CertificateFactory.readDERCertificate(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

Anyone know the exact issue here ?

Also i didnt change serverSecret & serverPublic under zkConfig. (I dont know how to get these). What it does mean by * # zkgroup config, run using your build jar * as in the documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. This exception came due to improper PEM format of reading cerKey file. Anyhow current crtKey form is PEM only, but it need a extended form of PEM.

i used below command to generate it.

```
openssl rsa -in cert.key -outform PEM -out cert.key
```

Then all above errors were disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I did enter the above command but i got this error

> Can't open cert.key for reading, No such file or directory
> 140021811573184:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:72:fopen('cert.key','r')
> 140021811573184:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:79:
> unable to load Private Key

and I did everything I could I generated all kind of certificate I could find on Internet but no change in result. could you please tell me what to do it's so important to me. thanks alot